# Is there a .css version for themes in ngx-sharebuttons for social sharing?

Tags: html, css, sass, angular9

I implemented `ngx-sharebuttons` and the buttons are loading fine as well as able to share.
The only thing not working is the theme styles are not getting applied because my angular project was created with .css when first created.

I see that the themes are available only in `.scss` and not .css. Also tried to convert the .scss to .css online but didn't help.

Do we have a .css version of circle-light theme of `ngx-sharebuttons` If what how can I convert my .css project to .scss. A bit skeptical to convert as I've kept that as the last option.

Thanks

Comment: how hard would be convert the project to use SCSS files for angular component's styles?

Comment: Thanks Massimo. I was initially scared to mess up but finally converted it. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I took a backup of the project and converted it to scss